# How to emit values from an array in the opposite direction starting from the last item?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Here's where I'am:

```
const observer = (item) => {
  console.log(item);
}

Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5])
  .take(3)
  .*******
  .subscribe(observer);
```

What I'd like to get in console is:

```
5
4
3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get that output, you can use `toArray` and `mergeMap`, but you need to compose them before the `take(3)`:

```js
Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .toArray()
  .mergeMap(array => array.reverse())
  .take(3)
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

That will work fine if you have an observable that emits a relatively small number of values before it completes. If you have an observable that emits an arbitrarily large number of values and you only want the last three - in reverse order - you could use `reduce` to avoid having to buffer every emitted value:

```js
Rx.Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .reduce((acc, value) => {
    acc.unshift(value);
    if (acc.length > 3) {
      acc.pop();
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .mergeAll()
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```